# .NET Framework 4.8.1 on Azure App Service?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have an ASP.NET MVC web app in Azure App Service that I am trying to upgrade from .NET Framework 4.8 to 4.8.1. It seems 4.8.1 isn't supported on Azure App Service. Is there any way currently to get 4.8.1 working? Additionally, when will Microsoft support .NET Framework 4.8.1 on Azure App Service?

Comment: Why do you need 4.8.1?

Comment: How you have deployed your App?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the Supported versions of .NET Framework in KUDU Console.

[image]

- I have taken references from this [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-language-dotnet-framework#show-supported-net-framework-runtime-versions) to check the .NET Framework supported versions.
- In KUDU, Navigate to the below path.

```cs
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework
```

and run `ls` command. You will get the list of Supported .NET Framework versions.

[image]

- You can see that Azure App Service supports only till v4.8.
- Even I have tried to set it using the below command without any success.

```cs
az webapp config set --resource-group RGName --name <app-name> --net-framework-version v4.8.1
```

- I have tried to deploy my sample .NET Framework 4.8.1 App to Azure App Service.
- You can see that the Runtime Stack is set as 4.8 itself.

[image]

- But the target framework in `web.config` file of the deployed app is 4.8.1 itself.

```cs
  <system.web>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.8.1"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.8.1"/>
  </system.web>
```

- I am able to access the app without any issues even with Runtime Stack 4.8.

[image]